# Poisson assumptions

Tags: poisson-distribution, assumptions, poisson-regression

I am dealing with a dependent variable that is either 0, 1 or 2 in theory it is unbounded and it can take values more than 2 so I am motivated to test Poisson model first.

The frequency counts for these outcomes, 0, 1 or 2 is as follows

```
  Var1   Freq
  0      433301
  1      989
  2      10
```

The mean, turns out to be  **0.002323279** , `mean <-  sum(tempdf3$pi*as.numeric(as.character(tempdf3$Var1))) ; mean <- round(mean,0) ; mean`

The standard deviation is **0.04867576**,  `sqrt(sum(((as.numeric(as.character(tempdf3$Var1)) - mean)^2)*tempdf3$pi))`

If i round the mean and standard deviation, `mean <- round(mean,0)`, and standard deviation `stdD <- round(stdD,0)`both are **0**

So is it safe to try Poisson regression on this dataset, since both the mean and variance are the same  ?

```
tempdf3 <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("0", "1", "2"
), class = "factor"), Freq = c(433301L, 989L, 10L), pi = c(0.997699746718858, 
0.00227722772277228, 0.0000230255583697905)), .Names = c("Var1", 
"Freq", "pi"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why you think rounding two different numbers off to 0 means they are actually the same.

Comment: @jbowman, Good question, I am not sure how to interept the mean value of `0.002323279` and standard deviation `0.04867576` when the outcome variable takes on any value from 0 to 1 or 2 or 10

Comment: Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value will help?

Comment: @jbowman, i know what expected value means, and the theory behind it, `The expected value in a die experiement is 3.5 etc`.. I am not not understanding what you are saying :)

Comment: Well, you are saying "I am not sure how to interpret the mean value...", which seems to indicate that you don't understand what it means...  If you know what expected value means and the theory behind it, what is the difficulty with interpreting the mean value of `0.002323279`?

Comment: @jbowman, my apologizes, I see where i am making confusing statements

Comment: No worries, I'm confusing (and confused) occasionally as well :)

Comment: The Poisson distribution with this mean indicates you should obtain only about one value exceeding 1 in a dataset this size, whereas you observe 10 of them. That's a significant difference. However, all this analysis is irrelevant because your regression model would not assume the response variable has a Poisson distribution: it assumes that the response *conditional on the explanatory variables* has a Poisson distribution. Thus, it looks like you're generating irrelevant (and possibly misleading) information with this line of inquiry. Consider *post hoc* GoF testing of a Poisson regression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Poisson distribution, the mean and variance (not sd) are assumed equal. In your example, var = 0.00236932961 (just by squaring sd). That's pretty close to the mean.

However, this does not confirm the validity of assuming Poisson distribution...

On a more practical note, there are R packages for estimations Negative Binomial dependent variable (`glm.nb()` in {MASS}) , etc. Also, you can test Poisson regression model for overdispersion, i.e. "mean = variance" against "mean < variance" in R. Check the {AER} package for `dispersiontest()`.

Comment: I agree, thanks for the suggestion, I will do that